# PHP / Mime Types - List of mime types publically available?

Tags: php, mime-types

I'm looking for an array, preferably php or json, that maps file extensions to mime types. This is intended to be a fallback for servers without Fileinfo, mime_content_type, or PEAR support.

Here is my pathetic list atm...

```
// Fallback for servers without Fileinfo, mime_content_type, or PEAR support.

$mime_types_map = array(
    '3dm' => 'x-world/x-3dmf', '3dmf' => 'x-world/x-3dmf', 'a' => 'application/octet-stream', 'aab' => 'application/x-authorware-bin',
    'aam' => 'application/x-authorware-map', 'aas' => 'application/x-authorware-seg', 'abc' => 'text/vnd.abc', 'acgi' => 'text/html',
    'afl' => 'video/animaflex', 'ai' => 'application/postscript', 'aif' => 'audio/aiff', 'aif' => 'audio/x-aiff',
    'aifc' => 'audio/aiff', 'aifc' => 'audio/x-aiff', 'aiff' => 'audio/aiff', 'aiff' => 'audio/x-aiff',
    'aim' => 'application/x-aim', 'aip' => 'text/x-audiosoft-intra', 'ani' => 'application/x-navi-animation', 'aos' => 'application/x-nokia-9000-communicator-add-on-software',
    'aps' => 'application/mime', 'arc' => 'application/octet-stream', 'arj' => 'application/arj', 'arj' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'art' => 'image/x-jg', 'asf' => 'video/x-ms-asf', 'asm' => 'text/x-asm', 'asp' => 'text/asp',
    'asx' => 'application/x-mplayer2', 'asx' => 'video/x-ms-asf', 'asx' => 'video/x-ms-asf-plugin', 'au' => 'audio/basic',
    'au' => 'audio/x-au', 'avi' => 'application/x-troff-msvideo', 'avi' => 'video/avi', 'avi' => 'video/msvideo',
    'avi' => 'video/x-msvideo', 'avs' => 'video/avs-video', 'bcpio' => 'application/x-bcpio', 'bin' => 'application/mac-binary',
    'bin' => 'application/macbinary', 'bin' => 'application/octet-stream', 'bin' => 'application/x-binary', 'bin' => 'application/x-macbinary',
    'bm' => 'image/bmp', 'bmp' => 'image/bmp', 'bmp' => 'image/x-windows-bmp', 'boo' => 'application/book',
    'book' => 'application/book', 'boz' => 'application/x-bzip2', 'bsh' => 'application/x-bsh', 'bz' => 'application/x-bzip',
    'bz2' => 'application/x-bzip2', 'c' => 'text/plain', 'c' => 'text/x-c', 'c++' => 'text/plain',
    'cat' => 'application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat', 'cc' => 'text/plain', 'cc' => 'text/x-c', 'ccad' => 'application/clariscad',
    'cco' => 'application/x-cocoa', 'cdf' => 'application/cdf', 'cdf' => 'application/x-cdf', 'cdf' => 'application/x-netcdf',
    'cer' => 'application/pkix-cert', 'cer' => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert', 'cha' => 'application/x-chat', 'chat' => 'application/x-chat',
    'class' => 'application/java', 'class' => 'application/java-byte-code', 'class' => 'application/x-java-class', 'com' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'com' => 'text/plain', 'conf' => 'text/plain', 'cpio' => 'application/x-cpio', 'cpp' => 'text/x-c',
    'cpt' => 'application/mac-compactpro', 'cpt' => 'application/x-compactpro', 'cpt' => 'application/x-cpt', 'crl' => 'application/pkcs-crl',
    'crl' => 'application/pkix-crl', 'crt' => 'application/pkix-cert', 'crt' => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert', 'crt' => 'application/x-x509-user-cert',
    'csh' => 'application/x-csh', 'csh' => 'text/x-script.csh', 'css' => 'application/x-pointplus', 'css' => 'text/css',
    'cxx' => 'text/plain', 'dcr' => 'application/x-director', 'deepv' => 'application/x-deepv', 'def' => 'text/plain',
    'der' => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert', 'dif' => 'video/x-dv', 'dir' => 'application/x-director', 'dl' => 'video/dl',
    'dl' => 'video/x-dl', 'doc' => 'application/msword', 'dot' => 'application/msword', 'dp' => 'application/commonground',
    'drw' => 'application/drafting', 'dump' => 'application/octet-stream', 'dv' => 'video/x-dv', 'dvi' => 'application/x-dvi',
    'dwf' => 'drawing/x-dwf', 'dwf' => 'model/vnd.dwf', 'dwg' => 'application/acad', 'dwg' => 'image/vnd.dwg',
    'dwg' => 'image/x-dwg', 'dxf' => 'application/dxf', 'dxf' => 'image/vnd.dwg', 'dxf' => 'image/x-dwg',
    'dxr' => 'application/x-director', 'el' => 'text/x-script.elisp', 'elc' => 'application/x-bytecode.elisp', 'elc' => 'application/x-elc',
    'env' => 'application/x-envoy', 'eps' => 'application/postscript', 'es' => 'application/x-esrehber', 'etx' => 'text/x-setext',
    'evy' => 'application/envoy', 'evy' => 'application/x-envoy', 'exe' => 'application/octet-stream', 'f' => 'text/plain',
    'f' => 'text/x-fortran', 'f77' => 'text/x-fortran', 'f90' => 'text/plain', 'f90' => 'text/x-fortran',
    'fdf' => 'application/vnd.fdf', 'fif' => 'application/fractals', 'fif' => 'image/fif', 'fli' => 'video/fli',
    'fli' => 'video/x-fli', 'flo' => 'image/florian', 'flx' => 'text/vnd.fmi.flexstor', 'fmf' => 'video/x-atomic3d-feature',
    'for' => 'text/plain', 'for' => 'text/x-fortran', 'fpx' => 'image/vnd.fpx', 'fpx' => 'image/vnd.net-fpx',
    'frl' => 'application/freeloader', 'funk' => 'audio/make', 'g' => 'text/plain', 'g3' => 'image/g3fax',
    'gif' => 'image/gif', 'gl' => 'video/gl', 'gl' => 'video/x-gl', 'gsd' => 'audio/x-gsm',
    'gsm' => 'audio/x-gsm', 'gsp' => 'application/x-gsp', 'gss' => 'application/x-gss', 'gtar' => 'application/x-gtar',
    'gz' => 'application/x-compressed', 'gz' => 'application/x-gzip', 'gzip' => 'application/x-gzip', 'gzip' => 'multipart/x-gzip',
    'h' => 'text/plain', 'h' => 'text/x-h', 'hdf' => 'application/x-hdf', 'help' => 'application/x-helpfile',
    'hgl' => 'application/vnd.hp-hpgl', 'hh' => 'text/plain', 'hh' => 'text/x-h', 'hlb' => 'text/x-script',
    'hlp' => 'application/hlp', 'hlp' => 'application/x-helpfile', 'hlp' => 'application/x-winhelp', 'hpg' => 'application/vnd.hp-hpgl',
    'hpgl' => 'application/vnd.hp-hpgl', 'hqx' => 'application/binhex', 'hqx' => 'application/binhex4', 'hqx' => 'application/mac-binhex',
    'hqx' => 'application/mac-binhex40', 'hqx' => 'application/x-binhex40', 'hqx' => 'application/x-mac-binhex40', 'hta' => 'application/hta',
    'htc' => 'text/x-component', 'htm' => 'text/html', 'html' => 'text/html', 'htmls' => 'text/html',
    'htt' => 'text/webviewhtml', 'htx' => 'text/html', 'ice' => 'x-conference/x-cooltalk', 'ico' => 'image/x-icon',
    'idc' => 'text/plain', 'ief' => 'image/ief', 'iefs' => 'image/ief', 'iges' => 'application/iges',
    'iges' => 'model/iges', 'igs' => 'application/iges', 'igs' => 'model/iges', 'ima' => 'application/x-ima',
    'imap' => 'application/x-httpd-imap', 'inf' => 'application/inf', 'ins' => 'application/x-internett-signup', 'ip' => 'application/x-ip2',
    'isu' => 'video/x-isvideo', 'it' => 'audio/it', 'iv' => 'application/x-inventor', 'ivr' => 'i-world/i-vrml',
    'ivy' => 'application/x-livescreen', 'jam' => 'audio/x-jam', 'jav' => 'text/plain', 'jav' => 'text/x-java-source',
    'java' => 'text/plain', 'java' => 'text/x-java-source', 'jcm' => 'application/x-java-commerce', 'jfif' => 'image/jpeg',
    'jfif' => 'image/pjpeg', 'jfif-tbnl' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpe' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpe' => 'image/pjpeg',
    'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpeg' => 'image/pjpeg', 'jpg' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpg' => 'image/pjpeg',
    'jps' => 'image/x-jps', 'js' => 'application/x-javascript', 'jut' => 'image/jutvision', 'kar' => 'audio/midi',
    'kar' => 'music/x-karaoke', 'ksh' => 'application/x-ksh', 'ksh' => 'text/x-script.ksh', 'la' => 'audio/nspaudio',
    'la' => 'audio/x-nspaudio', 'lam' => 'audio/x-liveaudio', 'latex' => 'application/x-latex', 'lha' => 'application/lha',
    'lha' => 'application/octet-stream', 'lha' => 'application/x-lha', 'lhx' => 'application/octet-stream', 'list' => 'text/plain',
    'lma' => 'audio/nspaudio', 'lma' => 'audio/x-nspaudio', 'log' => 'text/plain', 'lsp' => 'application/x-lisp',
    'lsp' => 'text/x-script.lisp', 'lst' => 'text/plain', 'lsx' => 'text/x-la-asf', 'ltx' => 'application/x-latex',
    'lzh' => 'application/octet-stream', 'lzh' => 'application/x-lzh', 'lzx' => 'application/lzx', 'lzx' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'lzx' => 'application/x-lzx', 'm' => 'text/plain', 'm' => 'text/x-m', 'm1v' => 'video/mpeg',
    'm2a' => 'audio/mpeg', 'm2v' => 'video/mpeg', 'm3u' => 'audio/x-mpequrl', 'man' => 'application/x-troff-man',
    'map' => 'application/x-navimap', 'mar' => 'text/plain', 'mbd' => 'application/mbedlet', 'mc$' => 'application/x-magic-cap-package-1.0',
    'mcd' => 'application/mcad', 'mcd' => 'application/x-mathcad', 'mcf' => 'image/vasa', 'mcf' => 'text/mcf',
    'mcp' => 'application/netmc', 'me' => 'application/x-troff-me', 'mht' => 'message/rfc822', 'mhtml' => 'message/rfc822',
    'mid' => 'application/x-midi', 'mid' => 'audio/midi', 'mid' => 'audio/x-mid', 'mid' => 'audio/x-midi',
    'mid' => 'music/crescendo', 'mid' => 'x-music/x-midi', 'midi' => 'application/x-midi', 'midi' => 'audio/midi',
    'midi' => 'audio/x-mid', 'midi' => 'audio/x-midi', 'midi' => 'music/crescendo', 'midi' => 'x-music/x-midi',
    'mif' => 'application/x-frame', 'mif' => 'application/x-mif', 'mime' => 'message/rfc822', 'mime' => 'www/mime',
    'mjf' => 'audio/x-vnd.audioexplosion.mjuicemediafile', 'mjpg' => 'video/x-motion-jpeg', 'mm' => 'application/base64', 'mm' => 'application/x-meme',
    'mme' => 'application/base64', 'mod' => 'audio/mod', 'mod' => 'audio/x-mod', 'moov' => 'video/quicktime',
    'mov' => 'video/quicktime', 'movie' => 'video/x-sgi-movie', 'mp2' => 'audio/mpeg', 'mp2' => 'audio/x-mpeg',
    'mp2' => 'video/mpeg', 'mp2' => 'video/x-mpeg', 'mp2' => 'video/x-mpeq2a', 'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg3',
    'mp3' => 'audio/x-mpeg-3', 'mp3' => 'video/mpeg', 'mp3' => 'video/x-mpeg', 'mpa' => 'audio/mpeg',
    'mpa' => 'video/mpeg', 'mpc' => 'application/x-project', 'mpe' => 'video/mpeg', 'mpeg' => 'video/mpeg',
    'mpg' => 'audio/mpeg', 'mpg' => 'video/mpeg', 'mpga' => 'audio/mpeg', 'mpp' => 'application/vnd.ms-project',
    'mpt' => 'application/x-project', 'mpv' => 'application/x-project', 'mpx' => 'application/x-project', 'mrc' => 'application/marc',
    'ms' => 'application/x-troff-ms', 'mv' => 'video/x-sgi-movie', 'my' => 'audio/make', 'mzz' => 'application/x-vnd.audioexplosion.mzz',
    'nap' => 'image/naplps', 'naplps' => 'image/naplps', 'nc' => 'application/x-netcdf', 'ncm' => 'application/vnd.nokia.configuration-message',
    'nif' => 'image/x-niff', 'niff' => 'image/x-niff', 'nix' => 'application/x-mix-transfer', 'nsc' => 'application/x-conference',
    'nvd' => 'application/x-navidoc', 'o' => 'application/octet-stream', 'oda' => 'application/oda', 'omc' => 'application/x-omc',
    'omcd' => 'application/x-omcdatamaker', 'omcr' => 'application/x-omcregerator', 'p' => 'text/x-pascal', 'p10' => 'application/pkcs10',
    'p10' => 'application/x-pkcs10', 'p12' => 'application/pkcs-12', 'p12' => 'application/x-pkcs12', 'p7a' => 'application/x-pkcs7-signature',
    'p7c' => 'application/pkcs7-mime', 'p7c' => 'application/x-pkcs7-mime', 'p7m' => 'application/pkcs7-mime', 'p7m' => 'application/x-pkcs7-mime',
    'p7r' => 'application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp', 'p7s' => 'application/pkcs7-signature', 'part' => 'application/pro_eng', 'pas' => 'text/pascal',
    'pbm' => 'image/x-portable-bitmap', 'pcl' => 'application/vnd.hp-pcl', 'pcl' => 'application/x-pcl', 'pct' => 'image/x-pict',
    'pcx' => 'image/x-pcx', 'pdb' => 'chemical/x-pdb', 'pdf' => 'application/pdf', 'pfunk' => 'audio/make',
    'pfunk' => 'audio/make.my.funk', 'pgm' => 'image/x-portable-graymap', 'pgm' => 'image/x-portable-greymap', 'pic' => 'image/pict',
    'pict' => 'image/pict', 'pkg' => 'application/x-newton-compatible-pkg', 'pko' => 'application/vnd.ms-pki.pko', 'pl' => 'text/plain',
    'pl' => 'text/x-script.perl', 'plx' => 'application/x-pixclscript', 'pm' => 'image/x-xpixmap', 'pm' => 'text/x-script.perl-module',
    'pm4' => 'application/x-pagemaker', 'pm5' => 'application/x-pagemaker', 'png' => 'image/png', 'pnm' => 'application/x-portable-anymap',
    'pnm' => 'image/x-portable-anymap', 'pot' => 'application/mspowerpoint', 'pot' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'pov' => 'model/x-pov',
    'ppa' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'ppm' => 'image/x-portable-pixmap', 'pps' => 'application/mspowerpoint', 'pps' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
    'ppt' => 'application/mspowerpoint', 'ppt' => 'application/powerpoint', 'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'ppt' => 'application/x-mspowerpoint',
    'ppz' => 'application/mspowerpoint', 'pre' => 'application/x-freelance', 'prt' => 'application/pro_eng', 'ps' => 'application/postscript',
    'psd' => 'application/octet-stream', 'pvu' => 'paleovu/x-pv', 'pwz' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'py' => 'text/x-script.phyton',
    'pyc' => 'applicaiton/x-bytecode.python', 'qcp' => 'audio/vnd.qcelp', 'qd3' => 'x-world/x-3dmf', 'qd3d' => 'x-world/x-3dmf',
    'qif' => 'image/x-quicktime', 'qt' => 'video/quicktime', 'qtc' => 'video/x-qtc', 'qti' => 'image/x-quicktime',
    'qtif' => 'image/x-quicktime', 'ra' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio', 'ra' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin', 'ra' => 'audio/x-realaudio',
    'ram' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio', 'ras' => 'application/x-cmu-raster', 'ras' => 'image/cmu-raster', 'ras' => 'image/x-cmu-raster',
    'rast' => 'image/cmu-raster', 'rexx' => 'text/x-script.rexx', 'rf' => 'image/vnd.rn-realflash', 'rgb' => 'image/x-rgb',
    'rm' => 'application/vnd.rn-realmedia', 'rm' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio', 'rmi' => 'audio/mid', 'rmm' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
    'rmp' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio', 'rmp' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin', 'rng' => 'application/ringing-tones', 'rng' => 'application/vnd.nokia.ringing-tone',
    'rnx' => 'application/vnd.rn-realplayer', 'roff' => 'application/x-troff', 'rp' => 'image/vnd.rn-realpix', 'rpm' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin',
    'rt' => 'text/richtext', 'rt' => 'text/vnd.rn-realtext', 'rtf' => 'application/rtf', 'rtf' => 'application/x-rtf',
    'rtf' => 'text/richtext', 'rtx' => 'application/rtf', 'rtx' => 'text/richtext', 'rv' => 'video/vnd.rn-realvideo',
    's' => 'text/x-asm', 's3m' => 'audio/s3m', 'saveme' => 'application/octet-stream', 'sbk' => 'application/x-tbook',
    'scm' => 'application/x-lotusscreencam', 'scm' => 'text/x-script.guile', 'scm' => 'text/x-script.scheme', 'scm' => 'video/x-scm',
    'sdml' => 'text/plain', 'sdp' => 'application/sdp', 'sdp' => 'application/x-sdp', 'sdr' => 'application/sounder',
    'sea' => 'application/sea', 'sea' => 'application/x-sea', 'set' => 'application/set', 'sgm' => 'text/sgml',
    'sgm' => 'text/x-sgml', 'sgml' => 'text/sgml', 'sgml' => 'text/x-sgml', 'sh' => 'application/x-bsh',
    'sh' => 'application/x-sh', 'sh' => 'application/x-shar', 'sh' => 'text/x-script.sh', 'shar' => 'application/x-bsh',
    'shar' => 'application/x-shar', 'shtml' => 'text/html', 'shtml' => 'text/x-server-parsed-html', 'sid' => 'audio/x-psid',
    'sit' => 'application/x-sit', 'sit' => 'application/x-stuffit', 'skd' => 'application/x-koan', 'skm' => 'application/x-koan',
    'skp' => 'application/x-koan', 'skt' => 'application/x-koan', 'sl' => 'application/x-seelogo', 'smi' => 'application/smil',
    'smil' => 'application/smil', 'snd' => 'audio/basic', 'snd' => 'audio/x-adpcm', 'sol' => 'application/solids',
    'spc' => 'application/x-pkcs7-certificates', 'spc' => 'text/x-speech', 'spl' => 'application/futuresplash', 'spr' => 'application/x-sprite',
    'sprite' => 'application/x-sprite', 'src' => 'application/x-wais-source', 'ssi' => 'text/x-server-parsed-html', 'ssm' => 'application/streamingmedia',
    'sst' => 'application/vnd.ms-pki.certstore', 'step' => 'application/step', 'stl' => 'application/sla', 'stl' => 'application/vnd.ms-pki.stl',
    'stl' => 'application/x-navistyle', 'stp' => 'application/step', 'sv4cpio' => 'application/x-sv4cpio', 'sv4crc' => 'application/x-sv4crc',
    'svf' => 'image/vnd.dwg', 'svf' => 'image/x-dwg', 'svr' => 'application/x-world', 'svr' => 'x-world/x-svr',
    'swf' => 'application/x-shockwave-flash', 't' => 'application/x-troff', 'talk' => 'text/x-speech', 'tar' => 'application/x-tar',
    'tbk' => 'application/toolbook', 'tbk' => 'application/x-tbook', 'tcl' => 'application/x-tcl', 'tcl' => 'text/x-script.tcl',
    'tcsh' => 'text/x-script.tcsh', 'tex' => 'application/x-tex', 'texi' => 'application/x-texinfo', 'texinfo' => 'application/x-texinfo',
    'text' => 'application/plain', 'text' => 'text/plain', 'tgz' => 'application/gnutar', 'tgz' => 'application/x-compressed',
    'tif' => 'image/tiff', 'tif' => 'image/x-tiff', 'tiff' => 'image/tiff', 'tiff' => 'image/x-tiff',
    'tr' => 'application/x-troff', 'tsi' => 'audio/tsp-audio', 'tsp' => 'application/dsptype', 'tsp' => 'audio/tsplayer',
    'tsv' => 'text/tab-separated-values', 'turbot' => 'image/florian', 'txt' => 'text/plain', 'uil' => 'text/x-uil',
    'uni' => 'text/uri-list', 'unis' => 'text/uri-list', 'unv' => 'application/i-deas', 'uri' => 'text/uri-list',
    'uris' => 'text/uri-list', 'ustar' => 'application/x-ustar', 'ustar' => 'multipart/x-ustar', 'uu' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'uu' => 'text/x-uuencode', 'uue' => 'text/x-uuencode', 'vcd' => 'application/x-cdlink', 'vcs' => 'text/x-vcalendar',
    'vda' => 'application/vda', 'vdo' => 'video/vdo', 'vew' => 'application/groupwise', 'viv' => 'video/vivo',
    'viv' => 'video/vnd.vivo', 'vivo' => 'video/vivo', 'vivo' => 'video/vnd.vivo', 'vmd' => 'application/vocaltec-media-desc',
    'vmf' => 'application/vocaltec-media-file', 'voc' => 'audio/voc', 'voc' => 'audio/x-voc', 'vos' => 'video/vosaic',
    'vox' => 'audio/voxware', 'vqe' => 'audio/x-twinvq-plugin', 'vqf' => 'audio/x-twinvq', 'vql' => 'audio/x-twinvq-plugin',
    'vrml' => 'application/x-vrml', 'vrml' => 'model/vrml', 'vrml' => 'x-world/x-vrml', 'vrt' => 'x-world/x-vrt',
    'vsd' => 'application/x-visio', 'vst' => 'application/x-visio', 'vsw' => 'application/x-visio', 'w60' => 'application/wordperfect6.0',
    'w61' => 'application/wordperfect6.1', 'w6w' => 'application/msword', 'wav' => 'audio/wav', 'wav' => 'audio/x-wav',
    'wb1' => 'application/x-qpro', 'wbmp' => 'image/vnd.wap.wbmp', 'web' => 'application/vnd.xara', 'wiz' => 'application/msword',
    'wk1' => 'application/x-123', 'wmf' => 'windows/metafile', 'wml' => 'text/vnd.wap.wml', 'wmlc' => 'application/vnd.wap.wmlc',
    'wmls' => 'text/vnd.wap.wmlscript', 'wmlsc' => 'application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc', 'word' => 'application/msword', 'wp' => 'application/wordperfect',
    'wp5' => 'application/wordperfect', 'wp5' => 'application/wordperfect6.0', 'wp6' => 'application/wordperfect', 'wpd' => 'application/wordperfect',
    'wpd' => 'application/x-wpwin', 'wq1' => 'application/x-lotus', 'wri' => 'application/mswrite', 'wri' => 'application/x-wri',
    'wrl' => 'application/x-world', 'wrl' => 'model/vrml', 'wrl' => 'x-world/x-vrml', 'wrz' => 'model/vrml',
    'wrz' => 'x-world/x-vrml', 'wsc' => 'text/scriplet', 'wsrc' => 'application/x-wais-source', 'wtk' => 'application/x-wintalk',
    'xbm' => 'image/x-xbitmap', 'xbm' => 'image/x-xbm', 'xbm' => 'image/xbm', 'xdr' => 'video/x-amt-demorun',
    'xgz' => 'xgl/drawing', 'xif' => 'image/vnd.xiff', 'xl' => 'application/excel', 'xla' => 'application/excel',
    'xla' => 'application/x-excel', 'xla' => 'application/x-msexcel', 'xlb' => 'application/excel', 'xlb' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xlb' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlc' => 'application/excel', 'xlc' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'xlc' => 'application/x-excel',
    'xld' => 'application/excel', 'xld' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlk' => 'application/excel', 'xlk' => 'application/x-excel',
    'xll' => 'application/excel', 'xll' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'xll' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlm' => 'application/excel',
    'xlm' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'xlm' => 'application/x-excel', 'xls' => 'application/excel', 'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xls' => 'application/x-excel', 'xls' => 'application/x-msexcel', 'xlt' => 'application/excel', 'xlt' => 'application/x-excel',
    'xlv' => 'application/excel', 'xlv' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlw' => 'application/excel', 'xlw' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xlw' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlw' => 'application/x-msexcel', 'xm' => 'audio/xm', 'xml' => 'application/xml',
    'xml' => 'text/xml', 'xmz' => 'xgl/movie', 'xpix' => 'application/x-vnd.ls-xpix', 'xpm' => 'image/x-xpixmap',
    'xpm' => 'image/xpm', 'x-png' => 'image/png', 'xsr' => 'video/x-amt-showrun', 'xwd' => 'image/x-xwd',
    'xwd' => 'image/x-xwindowdump', 'xyz' => 'chemical/x-pdb', 'z' => 'application/x-compress', 'z' => 'application/x-compressed',
    'zip' => 'application/x-compressed', 'zip' => 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'zip' => 'application/zip', 'zip' => 'multipart/x-zip',
    'zoo' => 'application/octet-stream', 'zsh' => 'text/x-script.zsh',
);
```

Edit: This script is for a buddy who isn't php/apache savvy. I don't know where it will be deployed - so I can't install PEAR or anything.

Edit2: Updated array from list in rfausak's comment - http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml

Comment: If there is a PEAR library that does the job (not sure if there is...) couldn't you just install it manually?

Comment: There're a few more in **svogal**'s comment over at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: @lonesomeday This script is for a buddy who isn't php/apache savvy. I don't know where it will be deployed.

Comment: @JohnHimmelman You can just download and include PEAR files as normal PHP files – that's all they are.

Comment: @lonesomeday Thx, I'll do that as a last resort. I'm trying to bundle everything into a single file for easy deployment (download.php)

Comment: @rfausak Thanks! I'll scrape that and edit post! :)

Comment: Nice and useful array. I am just unsure if overwriting keys is such a good idea. E.g.: `'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpeg' => 'image/pjpeg',`

Comment: I made this array http://pastebin.com/d4ZQBe5A by joining all the following lists + .php extension which is missing in all of them. 
please contribute to this list to make it as accurate and complete as possible.
https://gist.github.com/plasticbrain/3887245
http://pastie.org/5668002
http://pastebin.com/iuTy6K6d
total: 1223 extensions as of 16 November 2015

Comment: Array above is available here too: https://gist.github.com/nimasdj/801b0b1a50112ea6a997

Comment: @RustyFausak Dead link dude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using Apache .htaccess can be used to map mime types.

[moreinfo](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/mime-types-htaccess.html)
Here is [IANA's List of MIME TYPES](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the IANA doesn't list file extensions, so I can't scrape it

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/iuTy6K6d

Answer (score 15):

**June, 2022 update**:  The [mime-db](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db) project is the best source of mime DB type mappings that I'm aware of.  It aggregates MIME information from IANA, Apache, and NGINX, and is updated regularly, and publishes this information as a single JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't find the whole list in one page, but you can take a look around google. Good one is [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full) list