# How to validate a file type against its extension?

Tags: php, mime-types, mime, file-type

I want to create an uploader script and I want to define a few allowed file types to be uploaded, to prevent trick by renaming the file extension I use this array: [PHP / Mime Types - List of mime types publically available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519393/php-mime-types-list-of-mime-types-publically-available)
first it checks if file extension is allowed (e.g. .xsl) then it uses finfo to get mimtype to check with that array to see if mimetype matches the extension.

I uploaded an .xsl file, finfo retruns file type as application/octet-stream but that array for xsl extension returns application/x-msexcel so it will not be equal and not become validated.

Should I actually forget about mimetype matching with filename extension validator for the script and I should just check file extensions? or what should I do?

Comment: how did you ensure that the file type is "application/octet-stream", if you did this in the file array, it's not reliable, it can faked easily. The filetype header "application/octet-stream" is sent if none is recognized. that doesn't **not always** mean that the uploaded file is of this type. You should check the uploaded file, not the $_FILES array for mime-types

Comment: octet-stream is returned from finfo::buffer. Then I got the mimetype of xsl extension from array, it was x-msexell so they were not equall. How should I validate file mimetype against extensions to avoid renaming trick? Only provided extension lists are allowed so someone can rename it and upload it. How to validate?

Comment: well, I think you gave me the clue. I was using finfo::buffer so not reliable, I changed it to file_open with a physical file, and now it returns application/vnd.ms-excel instead of octet-stream as expected. but now another problem: how to validate if this is an allowed file as I renamed file name to .txt to trick upload? Should I use array_exists to pass this type to get the array key as .xsl to see that this is disallowed?

Comment: well i think, that is the point on validation. if the mime type is application/vnd.ms-excel it has to be a file with an excel extension, otherwise your mime type check would only be "half" secure :)

Comment: Generally, would you suggest to validate extensions against mimtype vs each other to prevent rename trick? Or it would be pretty nonsense and waste of time and only extension validation is enough to allow uploads?

Comment: I made this array pastebin.com/d4ZQBe5A or http://gist.github.com/nimasdj/801b0b1a50112ea6a997 by joining all the following lists + .php extension which is missing in all of them. 
please contribute to this list to make it as accurate and complete as possible. 
https://gist.github.com/plasticbrain/3887245
http://pastie.org/5668002
http://pastebin.com/iuTy6K6d

total: 1223 extensions as of 16 November 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are doing it right. You should never rely on the mime type headers, that are sent from the upload form, because you can fake that easily or it is not present, then you will often get the `application/octet-stream` header.

So it would be a good way to check if the file extension is matching the allowed mime type for this file extension.

I saw you linked this list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519393/php-mime-types-list-of-mime-types-publically-available). It´s surely a good list, but not really usable for php, because in the array is too much ovverriden, for example:

```
$mimeTypes = array(
    'xlm' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',//overridden
    'xlm' => 'application/x-excel',
    'xls' => 'application/excel',//overridden
    'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
);

var_dump( $mimeTypes );
```

This will only output two values instead of four, you should use an array like this:

```
$mimeTypes = array(
    'xlm' => array( 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-excel' ),
    'xls' => array( 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel' ),
    'txt' => array( 'text/plain' )
);

var_dump( $mimeTypes );
```

So you can simply check the mimetype with [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) if you already have the file extension.

This is a basic example you you could solve it. **NOTE:** This is not a working example, but I think you know where I want to point out:

```
// you have your file, you said it´s excel but you uploaded it with extension txt
$filepath = "excel.txt";

if( strpos( $filepath, '.' ) === false ) {
    // no file extension
    // return ?
}
// get the file extension
// well there is surely a better way
$filenameParts = explode( ".", $filepath );
$fileExt = array_pop( $filenameParts );// return the las element of the array and REMOVES it from the array

// your fopen stuff to get the mime type
// ok let´s say we are getting back the follwing mime type
$fileMimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

// now check if filextension is in array and if mimetype for this extension is correct
if( isset( $mimeTypes[$fileExt] ) && in_array( $fileMimeType, $mimeTypes[$fileExt] ) ) {
    // file extension is OK AND mime type matches the file extension
} else {
    // not passed unknown file type, unknown mime type, or someone tricked you
    // your excel.txt should end up here
}
```

Comment: What about files without extension? How do you dis/allow them to be uploaded?

Comment: For file size, is it reliable to use mb_strlen on $_FILES? Or only filesize on physical file should be used?

Comment: some extensions like .docs .docx .xlsm..... are not listed there. Can you help to add them please?

Comment: I made this array http://pastebin.com/d4ZQBe5A by joining all the following lists + .php extension which is missing in all of them. 
please contribute to this list to make it as accurate and complete as possible.
https://gist.github.com/plasticbrain/3887245
http://pastie.org/5668002
http://pastebin.com/iuTy6K6d
total: 1223 extensions as of 16 November 2015

Comment: I've updated the answer and added a condtion: `strpos( $filepath, '.' ) === false`, here you can retur false or whatever, if there is not fileextension, this will also avoid it, if the file itself is named "xls", for the file size I cannot give you a good advice, because I have no clue about file_size security in this context, I always use the filesize from the $_FILES array, had no problem with it

Comment: I think I don't have the time for it, but maybe you can upload it at your git account (if you have one) so people can fork or contribute. By the way you have docx at line 209